# Can I still rely on pipe(take(1)).subscribe() to run synchronously?

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

I'm trying to get the most recent state of an observable synchroniously. According to [this migration document](https://github.com/ngrx/store/blob/6a588ad755cc6511368a084b1bac94b260d24ed1/README.md#getstate-getvalue-and-value) for ngrx/store 2.0 `you can always rely on subscribe() running synchronously if you have to get the state value`.

I can't find any current documentation that supports this. Does this still hold for current versions of the store (e.g. 7.4.0)?

Sample code:

```
method(someId: string): string {
    let value: string;
    this.service.getSomeValue$(someId).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(s => value = s);
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to know if some code runs synchronous without diving deep into the source code, you can test it.

Set some asynchronous code (like `setTimeout` or `Promise` (first runs on Macro queue, second on Micro queue)), then code you want to test and then some synchronous code. Result should be:

- the code you test
- synchronous code
- asynchronous code

If result is like that, you code is synchronous.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
    method(someId: string): string {
        let value: string;
        this.service.getSomeValue$(someId).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(s =>
        value = s;
  return value;});

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

An observable will always have the most recent state (unless built to do otherwise).

And synchronous means that you don't use callbacks.

With that being said, you can simply use

```
async myFunc() {
  lastValue = await myObs$.fromPromise();
}
```

This will return, in a synchrnous way, the last value of your observable.